# How do I change the style of the header using ReactTable

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I need to change the default style to the style below

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. please provide minimal and relevant code which you tried isn't working. So that we can help

Comment: please refer the doc, https://react-table.js.org/#/story/readme. Just refer the Columns section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following css. You have to position the arrows properly.

```
rt-resizable-header -sort-desc:after {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  content : ' ';
  border-top: 20px solid #000;
}

rt-resizable-header -sort-asc:after {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  content : ' ';
  border-bottom: 20px solid #000;
}
.ReactTable .rt-thead .rt-th.-sort-desc, .ReactTable .rt-thead .rt-td.-sort-desc {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Could you put some examples of how to use it?

Comment: You have to override the react-table css. Will share the example shortly

Comment: @MithunGS Do you mind sharing how you managed to get it to override the table's normal css?  I've been trying for some time and can't get it to be applied

Comment: Both the css shown above for rt-resizable-header and the existing ReactTable css for rt-resizable-header show up in the page source but the new css never has any effect.  There must be something else that needs to be done?

Comment: @user3775501 Replacing the default 
`import "react-table/react-table.css";`
with your own
`import "../myPath/react-table-override.css";`
allows you to use locally modified css.

Comment: @JarrodL the problem with that though is it's creating bugs for later when react-table gets updated.  You'd have to re-copy the css for react-table and make the same changes to it locally.  Is there no other way to override just the one part?

Comment: @user3775501 Good point on future css updates. We override most of the css, but will have to manage future changes if they affect stylization.

Answer (score 8):

one other solution would be to return a custom component in the header section.`

```
 const columns=[
      { 
        Header:()=><small className="my_custom_class">Name</small>,
        accessor:"name"
      }]`
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update the css reference**

Within your class, replace `import "react-table/react-table.css";` with `import "../myPath/react-table-override.css";` to use your own modified css file located at [myPath].

**Update the css**

Replace the original css

```
.ReactTable .rt-thead .rt-th.-sort-asc,.ReactTable .rt-thead .rt-td.-sort-asc {
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

.ReactTable .rt-thead .rt-th.-sort-desc,.ReactTable .rt-thead .rt-td.-sort-desc {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
```

with the following css to remove the default box-shadowing and to add unicode arrows to the end of the header names.

```
.ReactTable .rt-thead .rt-th.-sort-asc,.ReactTable .rt-thead .rt-td.-sort-asc {
  div:first-child:after {
    content: " ▴";
  }
}

.ReactTable .rt-thead .rt-th.-sort-desc,.ReactTable .rt-thead .rt-td.-sort-desc {
  div:first-child:after {
    content: " ▾";
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Would need to be (extra {} removed) .ReactTable .rt-thead .rt-th.-sort-asc,.ReactTable .rt-thead .rt-td.-sort-asc div:first-child:after {
    content: " ▴";
}

.ReactTable .rt-thead .rt-th.-sort-desc,.ReactTable .rt-thead .rt-td.-sort-desc div:first-child:after {
    content: " ▾";
}

Comment: Have tried everything to get this to work but it doesn't.  Copied the css from react-table.css into a new file, made the changes and switched the import statement to the new one...import "../../components/ext-react-table.css" but nothing ever changes.  Have emptied the cache and done a hard reload.  If there is no reference to the css it still displays fine so not convinced that the css link does anything?

Comment: Well the css in "../../components/ext-react-table.css" is being used, have proven that so the css changes can't be correct, will go through the objects....

Answer (score 2):

I got the following to work, after copying react-table.css into a new file, amending as below and importing the new file wherever react-table is used.

The first two parts get rid of the ugly black border and the last two add the relevant arrows.

```
.ReactTable .rt-thead .rt-th.-sort-asc,
.ReactTable .rt-thead .rt-td.-sort-asc {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)
}

.ReactTable .rt-thead .rt-th.-sort-desc,
.ReactTable .rt-thead .rt-td.-sort-desc {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)
}

div.-sort-desc::after {
    content: " \25BC";
    float: right;
}

div.-sort-asc::after {
    content: " \25B2";
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Using the unicode characters looks cleaner than mine, I'm going to do that too.

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'react-table/react-table.css';
 use headerStyle property inside column prop.

  headerStyle: {
          background:'blue',
          textAlign:'center',
          color: 'darkorange',
          borderRadius: '5px',
          padding: '5px',
          border:'1px solid black',
          borderRight: '3px solid yellow',
          borderLeft:'3px solid yellow',
          borderTop:'3px solid yellow',
          borderBottom:'3px solid yellow'
          },
```